# Why is my Meteor.js publication not returning any results when I do filtering on the server?

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

I have a meteor.js app which I'm trying to productionalize. I have a collection UserEarnings which stores a record of "points" each user has earned. Right now, I'm publishing all records on the server:

```
Meteor.publish('userEarnings', () => UserEarnings.find());
```

And filtering the records down to only the relevant ones for the specific user on the client:

```
const composer = (props, onData) => {
   const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('userEarnings');
   if (subscription.ready()) {
      const userEarnings = UserEarnings.find({owner: Meteor.user()._id}).fetch();
      onData(null, { userEarnings });
   }
};

export default composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(AuthenticatedNavigation);
```

This is working perfectly well, but ideally I would be filtering on the server with:

```
Meteor.publish('userEarnings', () => UserEarnings.find({ owner: this.userId }));
```

Unfortunately, doing this yields no results returned when I call UserEarnings.find().fetch() on the client. Does anyone know why this might be? Note that I only subscribe to 'userEarnings' from the client when there is a signed in user.

I'm not sure if there's any other information that would be relevant but please let me know if you think there is. I'm running Meteor 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
Meteor.publish('userEarnings', () => UserEarnings.find({ owner: this.userId }));
```

to:

```
Meteor.publish('userEarnings', function userEarnings() {
  return UserEarnings.find({ owner: this.userId });
});
```

The reason why the first approach isn't working is because by using an arrow function you're setting the context of the publish function to be the callback. `Meteor.publish` requires a non-arrow function to properly set the context (and allow you to use `this.userId` properly).

Comment: Thanks so much! I was pulling my hair out trying to figure that out.